# Laravel belongsToMany with at least 1 relation

Tags: php, laravel

I try to define a simple query to find related models :

```
public function video()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Video', 'channel_video', 'channel_id', 'video_id')
        ->orderBy('review', 'desc')
        ->take(1);
}
```

I want to grab channels having at least 1 video in this relation. I tried something like :

```
$channelsWithVideo = Channel::with('video')->has('video')->get();
```

It grabs channels with video, but some are empty. Can I easily add a condition to grab only channels with at least 1 video ?

**EDIT**

It seems that `has` is enought to filter :

```
 Channel::has('video')->get();
```

I used `with` before, mistake I guess

Comment: Try using `whereHas`. `Channel::whereHas('video', function ($query)...`

Comment: You can use `->has()` and `->with()` together; they do different things. `->has()` (and `->whereHas()`) filters the parent query by it's child relationship, while `->with()` eager loads the relationship for more efficient querying. I.e. if you did `$model->something` without calling `->with("something")`, it would execute another DB query. This quickly causes an n+1 issue when called in a loop for large datasets.